# Need brief explanation about sms

Tags: sms

What is the gateway used for sending sms through the Internet in VB ... Please give me an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Typically sending an sms is actually sending an email.

For example, if your number is 123456 then you'd have to send a mail to 123456@your-providers-give-address.com

It depends on your provider, what is your sms "e-mail" address. So, there actually isn't an universal solution for this.